# Android app crashes when attempting to add AdMob to LinearLayout control

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, admob, android-linearlayout

I did several searches related to `AdMob` causing Android apps to crash because, well, my app kept crashing. I didn't have any success with it so far. After doing the research, I was able to narrow down the problem a fair amount, so now I'm asking for help to just pass this issue.

Here is the relevant code that I'm using:

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity{    

private AdView adView;
private static final String AD_UNIT_ID = "AD_ID";

@Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }

        adView = new AdView(this);
        adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
        adView.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);

        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
        layout.addView(adView); 
    }
}
```

That should be relatively straightforward, right? Now, according to the LogCat, the error occurs on the line `layout.addView(adView);`. This is where things get confusing for me; I have two layout files for the main activity in my app. The layout file it's referring to in `MainActivity.java` is `activity_main.xml`, which actually doesn't have a layout in it. For reference:

activity_main.xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.fongsoft.appname.MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

</FrameLayout>
```

The actual layout for the activity is stored in a file called `fragment_main.xml`, including the `LinearLayout` that I'm trying to refer to. So it looks like my problem is that I can't seem to find the LinearLayout control because I'm looking in the wrong file. Is there a way to fix this?

If I need to post any additional code or re-word anything, please let me know.

Also, as a side note: elsewhere in MainActivity.java, I seem to be able to refer to controls that are in the LinearLayout in `fragment_main.xml`. As an example:

```
public void refreshButtons(){
    Button button1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
}
```

In this case, it doesn't make sense to me that I can refer to and manipulate controls within that `LinearLayout`, but am having trouble adding to it.

***Logcat:***

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
     at com.fongsoft.appname.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:64)
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
```

**Edit:** The full LogCat can be found at http://pastebin.com/KhAPgU3r.

**Edit #2:** After adding in @Ken's suggestions, here's what my current code looks like:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity{
// Class constructor stuff.

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }
}

// ...

public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment{
    private AdView adView;
    private static final String AD_UNIT_ID = "AD_D";


    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        return rootView;

        adView = new AdView(getActivity());
        adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
        adView.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
        layout.addView(adView);
    }   
}

// ...
}
```

The line `LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);` is giving me an error that says, "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method findViewById(int) from the type Activity." What can I do in this case?

Comment: Move all your view element initialisation code (linearlayout, adview stuff) into your `PlaceholderFragment` `onCreateView()` method. Looks like all your views are in your fragment but you are trying to do stuff with them in your activity. Look further down in the file, there should be a `PlaceHolderFragment` inner class with an `OnCreateView()` method. This is where all this needs to go.

Comment: would you mind posting the Logcat error message here :)

Comment: @KenWolf, when I place the code in the `OnCreateView()` method, I get an error on the line `adView = new AdView(this);` that says, "The constructor AdView(MainActivity.PlaceholderFragment) is undefined".



@sai, I updated the post with the LogCat error.

Comment: Change `this` to `MainActivity.this`

Comment: @KenWolf That's done now, but now I'm getting the error, "No enclosing instance of the type MainActivity is accessible in scope". Do you want me to attempt to post the current code for that section?

Comment: I assumed `PlaceholderFragment` was a nested class inside of `MainActivity` which is why I suggested `MainActivity.this`. The `AdView` constructor takes a `Context` as it's argument. You'll need to supply it with one.

Comment: It is nested in MainActivity, so your assumption and suggestion were valid.

Comment: My mistake - change `this` to `getActivity()`

Comment: Aha, that did it, thank you.


There's also an error on the line, `LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);`, saying that it "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method findViewById(int) from the type Activity".


I feel like this should all be pretty self-explanatory, but this is my first real Android app so far. I've had a fair amount of experience with Java before, and I was able to figure out most of the app through reference material or whatever. But this has been a pain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing more research, I found a solution today that I can work with.

In the `fragment_main.xml` file, I have a traditional declaration for an AdView control, so I'm not creating the control via code.

In the `PlaceholderFragment` class, I modified the `onCreateView` function to read as something like this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

    AdView adView = (AdView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
        .addTestDevice("TEST_DEVICE")
        .build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);

    return rootView;
}
```

The problem was solved in the line `AdView adView = (AdView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.adView);`, when I used `rootView`, which basically allowed me access to `fragment_main`'s content.

Thank you to Ken and a bunch of other people on the internet for helping me figure this out. This problem haunted me for longer than I would have liked.